# Does the cost of MSDN Subscriptions represent a deterrent to .NET adoption

Tags: msdn

I know just the question is a bit of heresey, but I'm curious...

Sure, there are the express editions. But when Microsoft is effectively competing for 'hearts and minds' in an OSS world, it seems more than a bit counterproductive to charge devs who wholeheartedly support .NET high subscription fees for Microsoft software. It's hard to imagine that, in the context of Microsoft's overall sales, dev licenses represent such a significant revenue stream as to justify the downsides.

So my question is: do you know of any instances where MSDN subscription rates have deterred a team from adopting .NET for a project - where cost played a role in a decision to go OSS instead?

Answer (score 6):

I think MS has made huge inroads to making .Net cheaper to access and work with. With competent Express versions of Visual Studio and Sql Server, the only thing you need to pay for is Windows itself (both in your dev environment and server/production environment).

The only thing holding .Net back now is it may not be the right tool for every job regardless of cost.

Answer (score 5):

It does to me.  It makes me ask maybe I should try and become a Microsoft MVP because they get all the software for free.

You can't buy Expression Blend and Design for anything but the highest level on the License and that just ticks me off.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so, especially with the [empower program](https://partner.microsoft.com/40011351) for small ISVs -- $375 gets you 5 MSDN licenses and other goodies.  After that there are [Microsoft Action Packs](https://partner.microsoft.com/US/program/managemembership/actionpack) as well as the entire partner program.

Comment: The Empower program is $800 + GST in Australia. It basically equates to Visual Studio Pro + MSDN premium. There are conditions - 2 years only and not if you're MS cerified.

Answer (score 2):

I've always gotten legal, free copies of Visual Studio.  You can either download the Express versions which will handle most people's needs or go to the Launch events where they literally give out copies to everyone who shows up.

.NET Framework is a free download, so really the only thing left is a box running Windows.. and I'd be willing to bet that you've got one of those kicking around somewhere.

There's no reason to purchase an MSDN subscription.

Comment: I've got two reasons: VisualSVN and Resharper.

Comment: I think free copies being given away at launch events may differ from country to country. I've never seen free copies being given away at my local events.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a barrier to entry, but it certainly represents a glass ceiling. You get a lot of things with the Express editions, but not EVERYTHING. There's a lot of little perks that come with the Pro versions - addins for instance +cough+ Resharper +cough+. I'd say you need Visual Studio 20xx Pro at a minimum to do any mid-range to Enterprise level development.

The cost of MS developer tools was the sole reason behind my Year of Linux. It's tough seeing all the free development tools for Linux, OS X and Java. If my job didn't depend on keeping up to date with .NET, I'd leave it for dead in a heartbeat.

Answer (score 0):

In my view MSDN subscriptions are not a huge deterrant, as not only are there express editions, there are also trial versions of most products, and I think a basic MSDN subscription is not that expensive.

However licencing costs and licencing complexity of certain developer tools as well as certain products can be a huge obstacle which unfortunately is often not thought about at the beginning of projects.

I am aware of a number of projects which have chosen alternative technologies due to licencing costs and licencing complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently on the [Empower program](https://partner.microsoft.com/40011351) but I'll be paying the full fare when it runs out
 for the same reason I pay A$800/year for an AutoCAD subscription - it easily saves me more time & hassle than it costs in the long run by having everything I need at my fingertips.

I think I'm getting value for money when I consider both the licenses as well as the community - most of which I suppose is free anyway.

I consider it a legitimate cost of running my business and it's tax-deductible anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to restart my career, my life, etc and my previous MSDN Universal sub expired in 2005.  At the time it expired, I stopped working for a while.  That coincided with Microsoft changing the cost and structure of that subscription program.  To acquire a similar subscription today is out of the question.  I do not have the funds.  I am currently developing with old technology (VB6 and ASP) and will do so until I have the funds to purchase the MSDN sub that I want.  I have downloaded the "express" versions of VS 2008 and SQL 2008 but, lets be frank, any serious developer is going to want to utilize the features that arent available in "express".  In exploring this issue here on StackOverflow, I have seen others talk about the Empower program.  It looks promising and I shall investigate it.

But, yes, the barrier to entry is the cost.  Hopefully Empower lowers that, for a while.  I agree with the requirement that after it expires I will need to pay full fare.  I think thats only fair.